# Strange Date( )'s created with Strings containing NULL bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, null, v8, null-terminated

I know that JavaScript doesn't NULL terminate strings like C or C++ do, but I ran into a case which I can't explain.

Look at the following code (executed in Node.js v0.10.5) :

```
> new Date('123')

Fri Jan 01 123 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) // UNIX epoch : -58285702800000

> new Date('123\056')

Fri Jan 01 123 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) // UNIX epoch : -58285702800000

> new Date('123\0456')

Tue Jun 01 123 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) // UNIX epoch : -58272660000000

> new Date('123\0567')

Thu Jul 01 123 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) // UNIX epoch : -58270068000000

> new Date('123\0999')

Fri Jan 01 123 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)  // UNIX epoch : -58285702800000

> new Date('123\0555')

Sat May 01 123 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) // UNIX epoch : -58275338400000

> new Date('123\0655')

Sat Jan 01 12355 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) // UNIX epoch : 327718911600000
```

I'm not sure what's happening here, can someone explain it to me ?

It would seem that sometimes, the integers after a NULL byte define the month of the date, but the month not always correspond to the following number.

Comment: A NULL byte = `\x00`, not `\0`.

Comment: Actually both `'test\0other'` and `'test\x00other'` give the same result : `'test\u0000other'` because `\0`, `\x00` and `\u0000` are actually the same value.

Comment: `\x00` is always a NULL byte, regardless of what follows, while `\0` is only a NULL-byte when it is not followed by any digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are 3-digit octal escapes, not null bytes. So for example `'123\0456'` is realy `'123%6'`.

Comment: Oh ok right. So : `'\056'` equals to `.`, `'123'+'\056'` equals to `'123.'` and then `new Date('123.')` is the same as `new Date(123)`. I understand it now. ^^ Thank you for the quick answer !